# jQuery: How to find numbered position of class within group of classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of `img` elements with the same class.

```
<!--div of img elements-->
<div id="container">
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="three.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="five.jpg"/>
</div>
```

When one of these `img` elements is clicked, I'd like to log into the console the numbered position of that `img`. For example, if `<img class="square" src="two.jpg"/>` is clicked, I'd like the console to log `2`, since that element is the second element with `class="square"`.

**What I've Tried**

Referring to [this previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805301/jquery-using-each-to-get-position-of-a-class-element/40805338), here is what I've tried to use so far in my code:

```
<!--jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    //click an image with class="square"
    $(".square").click(function() {
    //find position of clicked image within classes "square"
    console.log( $(this).index('#container') + 1);

</script>
```

The result in the console is always `0`. What am I doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "#container" and it will give you the index of the element in the container.

From the jQuery API docs:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

```js
$(".square").click(function() {
    //find position of clicked image within classes "square"
    console.log( $(this).index() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="three.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="five.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".square").bind("click", function(){
    var imgs = $(".square");
    var curIdx = imgs.index($(this)); 
    alert(curIdx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <img class="square" src="one.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="two.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="three.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="four.jpg"/>
    <img class="square" src="five.jpg"/>
</div>
```